# Android How to stop function?

Tags: android

This is a part of application code :

```
        String isNormal = recvMessage[0];
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.status_normal);

        switch (isNormal) {
            case "0":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mygreen);
                break;
            case "1":
                countSec();
                int t = timer_sec[0];
                if (t > 5) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myred);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mygreen);
                }
                break;
            default:
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mywhite);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enter 0 or 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
        }
    }
```

countSec(); is timer function and timer_sec[0] is its result. t is seconds. I want to reset this function when the image change to 'myred'. How to stop this?

Comment: what do you mean by reset function, can you provide more information

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the question is that you start a timer in countSec(); and there you change the value in timer_sec[0].
the problem is the code runs fast and gets into timer_sec[0] before the count_sec[0] becomes >5. What I suggest is to do this:

```
        case "1":
           imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myred);       
                 }
           }, 5000);             

           imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mygreen);

           break;
```